Kubernetes envFrom equivalent in AWS ECS
What is the equivalent of envFrom when creating task definitions for AWS ECS?
Kubernetes has a very useful attribute envFrom which can reference secrets (link and all key-value pairs are automatically mapped to the container's env variable.
I've looked through the documentation on container definition, the container secrets, can only be referenced by name and valueFrom (using a specific key or it will be in JSON format - AFAIK).
Am I missing something, or do I have to painstakingly add all the variables and secrets one by one in the definition?

You have to add them all one by one.
